# java backed webscript doesn't show up at all

Tags: java, spring, rest, alfresco

I am following the alfresco wiki's guide to java backed webscripts and cannot get it to work. What's worse, I cannot get as far as generating errors in the logs or otherwise, or a webscript listing in /alfresco/service/index/all.

Other than the wiki example, I am not using an AMP but a jar for my classes. This is because I am bound to adding my webscripts to an existing app that currently builds to a jar.

As far as I understand, there are three major steps in creating a java backed webscript:

1. Create the java class
2. Register the bean
3. Place the descriptor

I implemented this as follows. File locations are relative to the jar's root.
**nl/mark/alfresco/myservice/webscript/GetFooTypes.java**

```
package nl.mark.alfresco.myservice.webscript;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript;
import org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.Status;
import org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptRequest;

public class GetFooTypes extends DeclarativeWebScript {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, Object> executeImpl(WebScriptRequest req, Status status) {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("types", "[\"foo\", \"bar\"]");
        return model;
    }
}
```

**alfresco/extension/templates/webscripts/nl/mark/cacher/footype.desc.xml**

```
<webscript>
    <shortname>Retrieve a list of foo types associated to a bar type.</shortname>
    <description>Returns an empty JSON array or a JSON array filled with foo types as Strings, named 'types'.</description>
    <url>/mark/cacher/footype?typecode={code}</url>
    <authentication>user</authentication>
    <family>Mark cacher</family>
</webscript>
```

**alfresco/extension/mark-context.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC '-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN' 'http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd'>

<beans>
    <!-- Java backed webscripts -->
    <bean id="webscript.nl.mark.cacher.footype.get" class="nl.mark.alfresco.myservice.webscript.GetFooTypes"
        parent="webscript">
    </bean>
</beans>
```

This `mark-context.xml` file contains other registrations too, which are correctly picked up.

Finally, this jar is placed in alfresco's WEB-INF/lib folder after which the server is restarted. However, the webscript is not available under its URL (404), and I find no mention of anything related in the (awefully clean) logs. It's also not listed in the webscripts index, not even as failed to load. I feel like I am messing up file locations.

Comment: Quick guess (have no running Alfresco here): rename the descriptor to "footype.get.desc.xml"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complete folder and file name

```
alfresco/extension/templates/webscripts/nl/mark/cacher/footype.get.desc.xml
```

defines,

A package of nl/mark/cacher,

A service id of footype,

A binding to the HTTP GET method

```
<bean id="webscript.nl.mark.cacher.footype.get" 
      class="nl.mark.alfresco.myservice.webscript.GetFooTypes"
      parent="webscript">
</bean>
```

The prefix webscript is picked up by the Web Script engine.
The ending get is picked up by the Web Script engine. It tells the Web Script engine which HTTP method to handle. In this case, an HTTP GET

So in your code, you missed **.get** in file descriptor file name

Reference: 
http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Scripts
http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Java-backed_Web_Scripts_Samples

Comment: I made a mistake in the question, the descriptor was in fact named `footype.desc.get.xml`. Which, indeed, is still wrong. Solution: `footype.get.desc.xml` as you said. Been stuck on this for over a day, I think I'll go and strangle something now :P. Thanks!

Comment: The Spring bean ID should be `webscript.nl.mark.cacher.footype.get`, as in the config supplied in the question. You are missing the service ID.

Answer (score 2):

I think the description file should be named `footype.get.desc.xml`